# AngularJS Checkbox Rendering Very Slow the First Time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm having an issue with a legacy app that's running Angular 1.5.9. The controller contains the following loop which is triggered by a "Select All" link on the page:

```
                var len = $scope.payments.length, i;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    $scope.payments[i].selected = true;
                }
```

The selected property in the objects in the payments array is bound to checkboxes in the view:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="payment in payments | orderBy: 'payDate'">
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="payment.selected" data-ng-change="setSelectedTotal()"/>...
```

There are up to 15000 items in the array/rows in the table, and the first time the Select All link is clicked after page load it takes up to 40 seconds for the view to refresh with all of the checkboxes checked. If I clear the checkboxes and then click the Select All link again, the checkboxes show as selected in about 1 second or less. This is true on all subsequent clicks of the Select All link-it's only slow the first time but takes a second or less every time after. I suspect this is related to something going on with model binding because when I surround the loop with console.time() and console.timeEnd(), the loop only takes a couple of milliseconds even on the first try. So the issue is with something that's happening after the loop completes. I've tried switching from ng-model to ng-checked just to see if it would speed things up but it gives me an error, and actually the app depends on the checkboxes being bound to the selected property. I also tried running a select all (followed by a clear all) on the first thousand checkboxes on page load but that didn't make any difference. Any insight into why it's so slow the first time and/or how to speed it up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does track by $index" improve the performance?

Comment: does it make noticeable difference if you remove orderBy?

Comment: btw, it would be good to see if you can reproduce it with a plunker with simplified model and it also helps others to see the issue and fix.

Comment: To @ABOS comment.. try sorting the items before binding them to scope. You could also try a paging strategy which payments it a subset of the actual array and a button (next page) which would choose the next subset of payments.

Comment: I guess the slowness is due to the first time angular is actually rendering the dom, but later on, it just updates it

Comment: Removing the orderBy does not help, nor does adding track by $index. There are no issues with the initial page load - the slowness occurs the first time the "Select All" link is clicked.

Comment: Actually the slowness is due to DOM rendering first time. Usually for large ng-repeat arrays, you could use virtual scroll that would effectively handle the rendering of large arrays. Try this https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat

Comment: 15000 items are just too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with some optimizations.

> Note : I made use of document.querySelectorAll to select/unselect outside of controller as it's much faster than relying on $scope data.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.payments = [];
        $scope.selected = false;
        $scope.total = 0;
        $scope.itemsCount = 7500;

        // Populate with 
        populate($scope.itemsCount);

        $scope.updateTotal = function() {
            let total = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < $scope.payments.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.payments[i].selected === true) {
                    total += $scope.payments[i].amount;
                }
            }
            $scope.total = total;
        }

        $scope.toggleAll = function() {
            // Toggle global selected state
            $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
            for (let i = 0; i < $scope.payments.length; i++) {
                $scope.payments[i].selected = $scope.selected;
            }
            $scope.updateTotal();
        }

        $scope.toggle = function(index) {
            $scope.payments[index].selected = !$scope.payments[index].selected;
            $scope.updateTotal();
        }

        function populate(count) {
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                $scope.payments.push({
                    amount: i,
                    selected: false
                });
            }
        }

    }]);


// Toggle all checkbox

function vanillaToggleAll(event) {
    var el = event.srcElement || event.target;
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = el.checked;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">

<h1>Items: {{itemsCount}}, Total: {{total}} USD</h1>

<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleAll()" onclick="vanillaToggleAll(event)">
     <label>Select/Unselect All</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="payment in payments | orderBy: 'amount'">
      <td>
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-bind="payment.selected" ng-click="toggle($index)" />
       <label ng-bind="::payment.amount"></label> USD
      </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>    
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

[A demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oykr3N2LPYors4RRxHIP?p=preview) with **7500** items to play with

And here are the results, I've used Chrome profiler to analyse time spent for loading, scripting, rendering...

**1000 items**

[image]

**10000 items**

[image]

**15000 items**

[image]

Comment: Code cleanup : I've removed code to select/unselect checkboxes from controller as it MUST NOT manipulate DOM but only $scope values.